# CSS li hover without li:after

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I have menu, where I use :after element. I am hovering li in menu, but it is hovering with :after element.

### HTML:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

```
/* MAIN MENU */
.main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: url("../img/li.png") repeat-x; height: 56px;
}
.main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    height: 56px;
    background: url("../img/li.png") repeat-x; height: 56px;
    line-height: 56px;
}
.main-menu li:after {
    content: "|";
}
.main-menu li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
.main-menu li:hover {
    background: url("../img/li-hover.png") repeat-x; height: 56px;
}
.main-menu .active {
    background: url("../img/li-hover.png") repeat-x; height: 56px;
}
.main-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d2eff3;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-menu li a:hover {

}
```

### JsFiddle:

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/fC8sb/)

### Question:

**How to exclude `li:after` element from hover efect?**

*(In menu hover effect is hovering under "|" separator. I want to disable hover under separator)*

### I tried:

```
.main-menu li:after:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

but no luck.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the hover effect should be on the link not on the whole li element http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/fC8sb/6/

```
.main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: url("...") repeat-x; height: 56px;
}
.main-menu li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    height: 56px;
    background: url("../img/li.png") repeat-x; 
}
.main-menu li:after {
    padding: 14px 0 0 4px;
    content: "|";
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
.main-menu li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
.main-menu li:hover a {
    background: url("...") repeat-x; height: 56px;
}
.main-menu .active {
    background: url("../img/li-hover.png") repeat-x; height: 56px;
}
.main-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d2eff3;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 16px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: solution: **hover effect should be on the link not on the whole li element** +1

Answer (score 1):

Position the `:after` element outside of the `li`. I did this in the example by adding the following code:

```
li {
    position:relative;
}

li:after {
    position:absolute;
    right:-3px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/fC8sb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Apply styles like this:

```
.main-menu li:hover::after  {
    background:red;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fC8sb/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `position: relative;` and `left: a` to your `li:after` so that the :after element is moved away from the li box.

Next, add some `margin-right: a*2` to your `li` so that `li:after` element won't just move to next `menu-item`.

Hope that helps.

Edit - Just to make sure: Replace `a` and `a*2` with numbers, eh?